# sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string\n

Tags: c++, django, docker, shell

I am making an online judge in django frame work I am trying to run a c++ program inside a docker container through subprocess. This is the line where I am getting error

```
 x=subprocess.run('docker exec oj-cpp sh -c \'echo "{}" | ./a.out \''.format(problem_testcase.input),capture_output=True,shell=True)
```

here **oj-cpp** is my docker container name and **problem_testcase.input** is input for the c++ file

**C++ code:**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    while (t--)
    {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        cout << a + b << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**problem_testcase.input:**

```
2
4
5
3
5
```

**error:**

```
CompletedProcess(args='docker exec oj-cpp sh -c \'echo "2\n4\n5\n3\n5" | ./output\'', returncode=2, stdout=b'', stderr=b'2: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string\n')
```

I am not getting what's wrong is in my code

Comment: What is the purpose of the decrementing the uninitialized variable `t`?

Comment: ohh sorry I forgot to write cin>>t but after doing so still i am getting the same error

Comment: It's vulnerable to a _shell injection attack_; you should avoid `subprocess.call(shell=True)` if at all possible.  Can you use the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead of using the `docker` binary?  This task also may be slightly easier to run in a new container rather than trying to use a debugging tool to launch a second process in an existing container (what's that container's main process?).

Comment: You did not specify what is your c++ program writes to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.call(shell=True)` has some significant security problems and I'd avoid it whenever possible.  It opens your application to a *shell injection attack*.  You're actually seeing this in your code: if the string in `problem_testcase.input` contains any characters that are meaningful to a shell, the shell will interpret them, which can cause it to do unexpected things.

In your input, *Python* expands the `\n` newlines and then hands them off to the host shell it launches.  So the shell command that's being run is

```bash
docker exec oj-cpp sh -c 'echo "2
4
5
3
5" | ./a.out '
```

and the shell stops at the first newline and tries to run the command up to there, which produces your error.  If the input string can be controlled, and you know `docker` commands work, it's actually straightforward to use this to take over the whole host.

---

The important thing to know here is that `docker exec` will pass its own stdin to the program it's running.  So you don't need the `echo input | program` syntax; since you don't need that, you don't need the `sh -c` invocation; and since you're only running a fixed command with no substitutions, you don't need `shell=True`.

```py
x = subprocess.run(['docker', 'exec', 'oj-cpp', './a.out'],
                   input=problem_testcase.input,
                   capture_output=True)
```

---

I might make two other changes to this program.

The [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) provides a more direct access to Docker functionality, without using `subprocess`.  It doesn't require a `docker` binary, though it still requires the Docker daemon to be running and for you to have permission to access it.

I'd also avoid scripting `docker exec`.  If you think of a container as a wrapper around a single process, `docker exec` starts a second process within that process, which is a little odd.  If you `docker run` a new (temporary) container, it starts up in a known state, and there's reduced risk of different program invocations interfering with each other.

```py
import docker
client = docker.from_env()

# Start the container (`docker run -d -i some_image`)
container = client.containers.run(some_image, detach=True, stdin_open=True)

# Send the input string into the container
socket = container.attach_socket()
socket.send(problem_testcase.input.encode('utf-8'))
socket.close()

# Let the program run, collect its output, clean up
container.wait()
output = container.logs()
container.remove()
```

Comment: Thanks for the information 
x = subprocess.run(['docker', 'exec', 'oj-cpp', './a.out'],
                   input=problem_testcase.input,
                   capture_output=True)
this works for me